# Change text of Bootstrap-vue Tooltip on click

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

i want to change Vue tooltip text on button click?

- Tooltip text before click: copy text
- Tooltip text after click: text copied

And when hover again it should show "copy text" again until i click again to change tooltip text.

```
<b-button variant="primary" id="copy">
   click here
</b-button>
<b-tooltip target="copy">
   copy text
</b-tooltip>
```

Note: I used [Bootstrap-Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tooltip#b-tooltip-component-usage) for this tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a data property called ``tooltipText` and update one you click on the button then reset it when the mouse leaves:

```
data(){
  return{
   tooltipText:'Copy text'
   }
}
```

template :

```
<b-button variant="primary" id="copy" @click="tooltipText='Text copied'" @mouseout="tooltipText='Copy text'">
   click here
</b-button>
<b-tooltip target="copy">
 {{tooltipText}}
</b-tooltip>
```